# Processing Illustrator or pdf files into XAML

Tags: xaml, pdf, adobe-illustrator, expression-design

What are the alternatives to process illustrator files or PDFs into XAML. My Current workflow works like this:

1. Open the PDF file in Adobe illustrator
2. Save the file as .ai (Adobe Illustrator) file
3. Open in Expression Design
4. Do some processing, mainly separating elements to layers and removing unneeded parts.
5. Save as XAML
6. Add XAML to Blend project

My only problem is that this way the text gets converted to paths. I would like to keep my text in XAML as well instead of paths.

Is there any other way to do this, so I keep the text? Any other tools?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294052/13241545). A detour using SVG lets you use Inkscape to create XAML and - in my experience - keeps text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a (free) Adobe Illustrator plugin to export to XAML. Not sure it does exactly what you are looking for, though.

Find it at http://www.mikeswanson.com/XAMLExport/

Comment: I tried this plugin and it works ok, but it converts the text in the document to paths. I would like to keep the text as text in the XAML document.

Comment: This plugin seems to have stopped working a long time ago, see also [Clint StLaurents comment here]
 ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153762/how-do-i-convert-an-illustrator-file-to-a-path-for-wpf#comment33893004_153930).

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is to have Glyphs elements instead of Paths.
The problem is that Glyphs elements require you to specify the URI of the font file. Also, Glyphs elements reference glyphs by their *index* into a font file (it may happen that a converter that generates Glyphs elements - like the Microsoft XPS Document Writer - uses indices into font subset files: so these indices may not be the right indices to the same glyphs as defined in the original font file). I have been able to "solve" this problem in two ways with my own PDF to XAML conversion tools.

**1. approach**: Embed the font-subset file, BASE64 coded, in the generated XAML code and have the application implement a class that, upon loading, extracts and decodes an embedded font-subset file to a temporary location and hands a valid URI to that temporary file back to the XAML loader.

or, **2. approach**: Have most font files already installed along with my application and, again, adding some support by my application that replaces the font name by an URI to the installed font file upon loading of the XAML code. The problem with this second approach is that glyph indices need to be correctly mapped to the installed font file, which may not be all that trivial to do. (You can find a link to an example file that has been generated for this way of loading on my blog: in particular take a peek at the file [truncatedcone-xaml.txt](http://www.mathcoach.ch/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/truncatedcone-xaml.txt))

In short: both solutions require a special PDF to XAML converter and support by the loading application. The reason I wanted to do it this way instead of just having my PDFs converted to Paths only is that my application is a shared whiteboard: thus I want my vector graphics to be as *small as possible*. (Conversion to paths tends to blow up the XAML code by a factor of 10 or more in most cases).

I am contemplating the implementation of a **third approach**: this would consist in generating the outline for every glyph that is used *only once* and then add support by my application to transform and position these glyph outlines in a way closely analogous to what Glyphs elements do that would otherwise have to be generated. The advantage would be that the generated XAML would still be relatively small (comparable to the second approach described above) without requiring the relevant font files to be installed along with the application and without having to map glyph indices from a subset file to the installed font file. The reason I have not yet tried to implement this in earnest is twofold: first, my current (second) approach already works very well for what I currently need; second, there might be performance problems with this third approach as reagards loading and / or rendering.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for taking the time and writing it up. I found a nice component called TallPDF that I hope can produce xaml out of the pdfs I have. it can create xps from pdf and now I just need to figure out how to make xaml out of xps.

Answer (score 1):

Well an XPS file is actually a ZIP file. So if you open it with a ZIP-archiver or if you rename its extension to ZIP you can see what is inside. It already contains the pages as XAML code (those files have the form [pagenumber].fpage). However, that XAML code may refer to other files (like raster images and font subset files, those are typically odttf files - basically encrypted true type files) that are included in that ZIP archive as well. Which means, that the XAML code that you find in an XPS document may not be directly usable as pure XAML in your application. I have written python scripts to do the conversion of XAML taken from XPS documents (generated by the Microsoft XPS Document Writer) to get XAML files that my application can load (see approaches 1 and 2 above). I could send you copies of those python scripts (they are not particularly great code, which is no problem for me since I am now using a different approach to convert PDFs to XAML anyway).

Comment: I would love to try your Python script. What is your approach to convert from PDF to XAML? I would like to keep the fonts and text if possible.

Comment: I left a comment on your site with my email address. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@gyurisc: Keeping the font file should work but keeping the *text* might turn out to be a problem, because, you see, *glyphs are not characters*. It might be that you could figure out the character by examining the font file that a given glyph is part of, but that would involve parsing the font file. If you are unlucky, your PDF to XPS converter does even not keep enough information in the font subset files to figure out the character a given glyph (very likely) represents.

For example: If I convert a PDF file to XPS with the help of Microsoft's XPS Document Writer, and then try to select a piece of text from that XPS document, I can (only apparently) copy it to the clipboard. However, if I then paste it back into a Word document, I get garbage. Whereas if I select that *same* piece of text in the original PDF document and paste it into the same Word document, I get reasonably meaningful text. So Microsoft's XPS Document Writer apparently does not care about the interpretation of a "glyph run" as text, and thus it seems very likely to me that the link between the glyph indices that one finds in the generated XPS code and the characters they are meant to represent is already broken at that point. (But, admittedly, that's just a guess.)

A representation of *text* (as opposed to a run of glyphs) would be a TextBlock element in XAML, I suppose. However, my guess is that a typical PDF to XPS converter is unlikely to generate TextBlock elements. XPS is mainly meant to be rendered - on screen or on paper - it doesn't suggest itself as a file format that is particularly suitable for data exchange (exchange of text in your case).

Comment: It kind of makes sense. I guess this is why did not find any text in my converted XPS files when I searched inside. Thanks for clearing this up!