# Get the text inside a xaml file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have around 200 xaml files that was generated from Illustrator so the text inside them is in this format:

```
>     <Canvas Name="TextBlock" Height="338.674" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="378.608">
>                       <Path Data="F1M66.54195,312.7368L66.54195,311.1118L57.807575,311.1118L57.807575,295.64305L55.97945,295.64305L55.97945,312.7368L66.54195,312.7368"
> Fill="Black" Height="17.094" Canvas.Left="1.75" Stretch="Fill"
> Canvas.Top="85.899" Width="10.562"/>
>                       <Path Data="F1M78.4502,306.83055C78.4502,305.002425,78.2002,303.346175,77.0127,302.127425C76.184575,301.314925,75.059575,300.783675,73.622075,300.783675C72.184575,300.783675,71.059575,301.314925,70.23145,302.127425C69.04395,303.346175,68.79395,305.002425,68.79395,306.83055C68.79395,308.658675,69.04395,310.314925,70.23145,311.533675C71.059575,312.346175,72.184575,312.877425,73.622075,312.877425C75.059575,312.877425,76.184575,312.346175,77.0127,311.533675C78.2002,310.314925,78.4502,308.658675,78.4502,306.83055
> M76.715825,306.83055C76.715825,308.158675,76.653325,309.6118,75.778325,310.4868C75.23145,311.033675,74.465825,311.346175,73.622075,311.346175C72.778325,311.346175,72.04395,311.033675,71.48145,310.4868C70.622075,309.6118,70.528325,308.158675,70.528325,306.83055C70.528325,305.51805,70.622075,304.0493,71.48145,303.189925C72.04395,302.627425,72.778325,302.314925,73.622075,302.314925C74.465825,302.314925,75.23145,302.627425,75.778325,303.189925C76.653325,304.0493,76.715825,305.51805,76.715825,306.83055" Fill="Black" Height="12.094" Canvas.Left="14.565" Stretch="Fill"
> Canvas.Top="91.04" Width="9.656"/>
>                       <Path Data="F1M91.310825,312.7368L91.310825,300.9243L89.57645,300.9243L89.57645,308.20555C89.57645,310.26805,88.404575,311.346175,86.623325,311.346175C84.8577,311.346175,83.748325,310.283675,83.748325,308.20555L83.748325,300.9243L82.029575,300.9243L82.029575,308.471175C82.029575,309.83055,82.38895,310.95555,83.217075,311.783675C83.935825,312.502425,84.998325,312.877425,86.26395,312.877425C87.592075,312.877425,88.76395,312.377425,89.6077,311.4243L89.6077,312.7368L91.310825,312.7368"
> Fill="Black" Height="11.953" Canvas.Left="27.8" Stretch="Fill"
> Canvas.Top="91.18" Width="9.281"/>
```

My question is: can i generate these letters as text using c# code?

Comment: 2 ways come to mind like put them in a XPS document shell or a WPF window?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I interpreted the question quite differently than @jageen did. So we need to know what it is you want.

Comment: i need to do a small windows app let's say, that read this xaml file and save the text inside it to text file, the text is now in the format above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this answer to [Processing Illustrator or pdf files into XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551180/processing-illustrator-or-pdf-files-into-xaml): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536756/563088

In short: the exporter has to support it. It i snearly impossible to turn paths back in to glyphs/text. That is OCR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do 
you can use xml deserialization,

what you need for it is 
1 >A Xsd file for validation ( if you want )
2 > A class file which can store data of you xml file

you can use Xsd.exe for create class from Xsd file.
and for create Xsd file for xml.
Open Xml file in C# IDE and go to 
Schema menu > create Xsd file.

for help 
here is links 
[How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) ( example of  deserialization )
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ( help for Xsd.exe )

Comment: if you get any problem in creating Xsd file or class file let me knw :)
Best of luck.

Comment: How is this going to turn paths into text?

Comment: You mean you want
<Path Data="F1M66.54195,312.7368L66.54195,311.1118L57.807575,311.1118L57.807575,295.64305L55.97945,295.64305L55.97945,312.7368L66.54195,312.7368"

in text ?

Comment: I thought the question was about turning the paths into text but I might be wrong...

Comment: yes i need this: <Path Data="F1M66.54195,312.7368L66.54195,311.1118L57.807575,311.1118L57.807575,295.64305L55.97945,295.64305L55.97945,312.7368L66.54195,312.7368"
> Fill="Black" Height="17.094" Canvas.Left="1.75" Stretch="Fill"
> Canvas.Top="85.899" Width="10.562"/> to be "S" for example

Comment: I am right now busy with my project otherwise i will surely send you code but for now hee is a link 

http://www.kirupa.com/net/reading_xml_directly_pg1.htm 

it show an example how you can read property value of tag in xml

Comment: @jageen - are you sure you are going to be able to translate the path in to a literal "S"?

Comment: What i understand from you question is..
You want that path Data value in string is it k ?


It will helps u to get

F1M66.54195,312.7368L66.54195,311.1118L57.807575,311.1118L57.807575,295.64305L55.97945,295.64305L55.97945,312.7368L66.54195,312.7368

from Path tag.