# Determining Path.Data in Xamarin Forms 4.7 from an SVG starting point

Tags: xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms, path

I am excited about the Inclusion of Shapes and Geometries into XAM Forms 4.7 even if it is Experimental. I have several svg files i want to use as starting points for Shapes.Path.Data statements in XAML.

In the ShapesDemo app I see The XAML and the SVG it was based on. Both are attached. How did those SVG Paths get distilled To those XAML path statements?

the demo is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-shapesdemos/

the image for consideration:
[image]
Attached are the source SVG and the Related Xaml Path.Data transformations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-shapesdemos/

the Path.Data in that sample has the xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ShapesDemos.MonkeyFaceDemoPage"
             Title="Monkey face demo">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center"
          VerticalOptions="Center">
        <!-- Path data from SVG athttps://openclipart.org/detail/86599/monkey-face -->
        <Path Fill="#FF502D16" Data="M122.037181 73.3037037 C122.037181 109.1 94.9029248 138.118519 61.4299587 138.118519 C27.9581001 138.118519 0.822736364 109.1 0.822736364 73.3037037 C0.822736364 37.5074074 27.9569926 8.48888889 61.4299587 8.48888889 C94.9018174 8.48888889 122.037181 37.5074074 122.037181 73.3037037 L122.037181 73.3037037 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FFA05A2C" Data="M106.19796 83.3331702 C106.19796 108.901749 87.6972207 129.629096 64.8746074 129.629096 C42.0527494 129.629096 23.5512546 108.901749 23.5512546 83.3331702 C23.5512546 57.7645917 42.0519943 37.0372443 64.8746074 37.0372443 C87.6964653 37.0372443 106.19796 57.7645917 106.19796 83.3331702 L106.19796 83.3331702 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF502D16" Data="M399.5909 72.5324074 C399.5909 108.328704 372.456644 137.347222 338.983678 137.347222 C305.511819 137.347222 278.376455 108.328704 278.376455 72.5324074 C278.376455 36.7361111 305.510712 7.71759259 338.983678 7.71759259 C372.455536 7.71759259 399.5909 36.7361111 399.5909 72.5324074 L399.5909 72.5324074 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FFA05A2C" Data="M383.751679 82.5618739 C383.751679 108.130453 365.25094 128.8578 342.428326 128.8578 C319.606469 128.8578 301.104974 108.130453 301.104974 82.5618739 C301.104974 56.9932954 319.605713 36.265948 342.428326 36.265948 C365.250184 36.265948 383.751679 56.9932954 383.751679 82.5618739 L383.751679 82.5618739 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF502D16" Data="M201.239669 0 C411.099174 18.7805556 397.256198 277.296296 198.487603 361.111111 C-19.7024793 254.833333 9.68595041 9.06481481 201.239669 0 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FFD38D5F" Data="M201.239669 58.9472222 C377.297521 12.8824074 325.305785 234.169444 205.371901 250.308333 C89.5206612 249.289815 2.2892562 10.5398148 201.239669 58.9472222 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M267.387938 122.225395 C267.600827 141.380032 256.658967 156.769338 242.947772 156.599025 C229.236577 156.428712 217.949569 140.763291 217.73668 121.608655 C217.523791 102.454017 228.465651 87.0647113 242.176846 87.2350243 C255.888041 87.4053373 267.175049 103.070758 267.387938 122.225395 Z" />
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M175.101775 122.379402 C174.888887 141.534039 163.601877 157.19946 149.890683 157.369773 C136.179488 157.540086 125.237629 142.15078 125.450517 122.996143 C125.663406 103.841505 136.950414 88.1760849 150.661609 88.0057719 C164.372804 87.8354589 175.314664 103.224764 175.101775 122.379402 Z" />
        <Path Fill="#FFD38D5F" Data="M326.308234 269.31113 C326.308234 341.333278 270.498044 399.718537 201.650289 399.718537 C132.804813 399.718537 76.992345 341.333278 76.992345 269.31113 C76.992345 197.288981 132.802535 138.903722 201.650289 138.903722 C270.495765 138.903722 326.308234 197.288981 326.308234 269.31113 L326.308234 269.31113 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M104.702479 345.225 C169.520661 360.787037 234.338843 366.664815 299.157025 341.8375 C243.776033 368.156019 181.991736 377.384722 104.702479 345.225 L104.702479 345.225 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M198.066116 174.993519 C195.075124 227.067593 194.034463 279.123148 199.177686 331.113889 C193.755041 286.700926 191.76 237.113889 198.066116 174.993519 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M183.330579 195.215741 C183.330579 203.3125 181.172149 209.875926 178.509669 209.875926 C175.847107 209.875926 173.68876 203.312222 173.68876 195.215741 C173.68876 187.118981 175.84719 180.555556 178.509669 180.555556 C181.172231 180.555556 183.330579 187.119259 183.330579 195.215741 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FF241F1C" Data="M220.107438 195.061111 C220.107438 203.15787 217.949008 209.721296 215.286529 209.721296 C212.623967 209.721296 210.46562 203.157593 210.46562 195.061111 C210.46562 186.964352 212.62405 180.400926 215.286529 180.400926 C217.949091 180.400926 220.107438 186.96463 220.107438 195.061111 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FFE3DEDB" Data="M263.347107 112.197222 C262.180579 131.525926 252.966942 138.837963 240.640496 141.500926 C248.209256 142.496667 252.414876 151.85 259.983471 136.771574 C261.643719 128.885556 265.049835 122.658611 263.34686 112.196574 L263.347107 112.197222 Z"/>
        <Path Fill="#FFE3DEDB" Data="M167.917355 108.428704 C171.621488 126.532407 164.771901 136.184259 153.840496 142.568519 C161.206612 141.06213 167.485124 148.2975 170.858678 132.046296 C170.461355 124.281759 172.118099 117.480556 167.917686 108.428704 L167.917355 108.428704 Z"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

This was derived from the base SVG

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:ns1="http://sozi.baierouge.fr"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    id="svg5825"
    sodipodi:docname="New document 35"
    viewBox="0 0 482.5 431.67"
    version="1.1"
    inkscape:version="0.47 r22583"
  >
  <sodipodi:namedview
      id="base"
      bordercolor="#666666"
      inkscape:pageshadow="2"
      inkscape:window-y="58"
      pagecolor="#ffffff"
      inkscape:window-height="839"
      inkscape:window-maximized="0"
      inkscape:zoom="1"
      inkscape:window-x="117"
      showgrid="false"
      borderopacity="1.0"
      inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
      inkscape:cx="252.01705"
      inkscape:cy="218.33333"
      inkscape:window-width="693"
      inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
      inkscape:document-units="px"
  />
  <g
      id="layer1"
      inkscape:label="Layer 1"
      inkscape:groupmode="layer"
      transform="translate(-152.5 -86.667)"
    >
    <g
        id="g6873"
      >
      <path
          id="path5837-9"
          sodipodi:rx="164.16667"
          sodipodi:ry="140"
          style="fill:#502d16"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m371.67 411.67c0 77.32-73.5 140-164.17 140-90.667 0-164.17-62.68-164.17-140s73.5-140 164.17-140c90.667 0 164.17 62.68 164.17 140z"
          transform="matrix(.44670 0 0 0.5 133.14 -40)"
          sodipodi:cy="411.66666"
          sodipodi:cx="207.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path5837-9-3"
          sodipodi:rx="164.16667"
          sodipodi:ry="140"
          style="fill:#a05a2c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m371.67 411.67c0 77.32-73.5 140-164.17 140-90.667 0-164.17-62.68-164.17-140s73.5-140 164.17-140c90.667 0 164.17 62.68 164.17 140z"
          transform="matrix(.30457 0 0 .35714 166.8 29.643)"
          sodipodi:cy="411.66666"
          sodipodi:cx="207.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path5837-9-38"
          sodipodi:rx="164.16667"
          sodipodi:ry="140"
          style="fill:#502d16"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m371.67 411.67c0 77.32-73.5 140-164.17 140-90.667 0-164.17-62.68-164.17-140s73.5-140 164.17-140c90.667 0 164.17 62.68 164.17 140z"
          transform="matrix(.44670 0 0 0.5 468.98 -40.833)"
          sodipodi:cy="411.66666"
          sodipodi:cx="207.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path5837-9-3-4"
          sodipodi:rx="164.16667"
          sodipodi:ry="140"
          style="fill:#a05a2c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m371.67 411.67c0 77.32-73.5 140-164.17 140-90.667 0-164.17-62.68-164.17-140s73.5-140 164.17-140c90.667 0 164.17 62.68 164.17 140z"
          transform="matrix(.30457 0 0 .35714 502.64 28.81)"
          sodipodi:cy="411.66666"
          sodipodi:cx="207.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path5835"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc"
          style="fill:#502d16"
          d="m395 86.667c253.93 20.283 237.18 299.48-3.33 390-264.01-114.78-228.45-380.21 3.33-390z"
      />
      <path
          id="path5952"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc"
          style="fill:#d38d5f"
          d="m395 150.33c213.03-49.75 150.12 189.24 5 206.67-140.18-1.1-245.73-258.95-5-206.67z"
      />
      <path
          id="path6770-6"
          sodipodi:rx="30"
          sodipodi:ry="37.5"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m101.67 289.17c0 20.711-13.431 37.5-30 37.5s-30-16.789-30-37.5 13.431-37.5 30-37.5 30 16.789 30 37.5z"
          transform="matrix(.99459 .10389 -.10389 .99459 403.76 -76.714)"
          sodipodi:cy="289.16666"
          sodipodi:cx="71.666664"
      />
      <path
          id="path6770"
          sodipodi:rx="30"
          sodipodi:ry="37.5"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m101.67 289.17c0 20.711-13.431 37.5-30 37.5s-30-16.789-30-37.5 13.431-37.5 30-37.5 30 16.789 30 37.5z"
          transform="matrix(.99459 -.10389 .10389 .99459 232.01 -60.99)"
          sodipodi:cy="289.16666"
          sodipodi:cx="71.666664"
      />
      <path
          id="path5837"
          sodipodi:rx="164.16667"
          sodipodi:ry="140"
          style="fill:#d38d5f"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m371.67 411.67c0 77.32-73.5 140-164.17 140-90.667 0-164.17-62.68-164.17-140s73.5-140 164.17-140c90.667 0 164.17 62.68 164.17 140z"
          transform="matrix(.91878 0 0 1.006 204.85 -36.617)"
          sodipodi:cy="411.66666"
          sodipodi:cx="207.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path6722"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          d="m278.19 459.51c78.43 16.807 156.86 23.155 235.29-3.6585-67.011 28.424-141.77 38.391-235.29 3.6585z"
      />
      <path
          id="path6722-5"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          d="m391.16 275.66c-3.6191 56.24-4.8783 112.46 1.345 168.61-6.5614-47.966-8.9754-101.52-1.345-168.61z"
      />
      <path
          id="path6746"
          sodipodi:rx="5.8333335"
          sodipodi:ry="15.833333"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m138.33 327.5c0 8.7445-2.6117 15.833-5.8333 15.833-3.2217 0-5.8333-7.0888-5.8333-15.833 0-8.7445 2.6117-15.833 5.8333-15.833 3.2217 0 5.8333 7.0888 5.8333 15.833z"
          transform="translate(235,-30)"
          sodipodi:cy="327.5"
          sodipodi:cx="132.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path6746-0"
          sodipodi:rx="5.8333335"
          sodipodi:ry="15.833333"
          style="fill:#241f1c"
          sodipodi:type="arc"
          d="m138.33 327.5c0 8.7445-2.6117 15.833-5.8333 15.833-3.2217 0-5.8333-7.0888-5.8333-15.833 0-8.7445 2.6117-15.833 5.8333-15.833 3.2217 0 5.8333 7.0888 5.8333 15.833z"
          transform="translate(279.5 -30.167)"
          sodipodi:cy="327.5"
          sodipodi:cx="132.5"
      />
      <path
          id="path6830"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="cccc"
          style="fill:#e3dedb"
          d="m470.15 207.84c-1.4115 20.875-12.56 28.772-27.475 31.648 9.1582 1.0754 14.247 11.177 23.405-5.1077 2.0089-8.5169 6.1303-15.242 4.0697-26.541z"
      />
      <path
          id="path6830-8"
          sodipodi:nodetypes="cccc"
          style="fill:#e3dedb"
          d="m354.68 203.77c4.482 19.552-3.806 29.976-17.033 36.871 8.913-1.6269 16.51 6.1873 20.592-11.364-0.48076-8.3857 1.5239-15.731-3.5586-25.507z"
      />
    </g
    >
  </g
  >
  <metadata
    >
    <rdf:RDF
      >
      <cc:Work
        >
        <dc:format
          >image/svg+xml</dc:format
        >
        <dc:type
            rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"
        />
        <cc:license
            rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/"
        />
        <dc:publisher
          >
          <cc:Agent
              rdf:about="http://openclipart.org/"
            >
            <dc:title
              >Openclipart</dc:title
            >
          </cc:Agent
          >
        </dc:publisher
        >
        <dc:title
          >Monkey Face</dc:title
        >
        <dc:date
          >2010-09-25T05:06:29</dc:date
        >
        <dc:description
          >Based on a photo of my favorite cuddly monkey Jefro.</dc:description
        >
        <dc:source
          >https://openclipart.org/detail/86599/monkey-face-by-stevepetmonkey</dc:source
        >
        <dc:creator
          >
          <cc:Agent
            >
            <dc:title
              >stevepetmonkey</dc:title
            >
          </cc:Agent
          >
        </dc:creator
        >
        <dc:subject
          >
          <rdf:Bag
            >
            <rdf:li
              >Jungle Animal</rdf:li
            >
            <rdf:li
              >Monkey</rdf:li
            >
            <rdf:li
              >Monkey Face</rdf:li
            >
          </rdf:Bag
          >
        </dc:subject
        >
      </cc:Work
      >
      <cc:License
          rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/"
        >
        <cc:permits
            rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Reproduction"
        />
        <cc:permits
            rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Distribution"
        />
        <cc:permits
            rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#DerivativeWorks"
        />
      </cc:License
      >
    </rdf:RDF
    >
  </metadata
  >
</svg
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you have to convert the SVG with a designer tool (E.g. Adobe Illustrator and/or other tools/plugins) to export the SVG as XAML geometries. One usefull tool could be https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors

See also discussion found here: [How do I convert an Illustrator file to a path for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153762/how-do-i-convert-an-illustrator-file-to-a-path-for-wpf)

But what I would recommend is to render SVG images via SkiaSharp SKCanvasView. Write your own SvgImage class. Its will save you lots of App memory (no png and not bitmaps needed) and works nicely out of Xamarin.Forms for all plattforms like Android, iOS, UWP.
See [How to load file .svg with SkiaSharp on Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259473/how-to-load-file-svg-with-skiasharp-on-xamarin-forms)

Comment: The cool answer that I have tradionally used is the accepted answer: "How do I convert an Illustrator file to a path for WPF" Microsoft now has removed that item from downloads.  I will likely look into custom class approach